# Solving integrals using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Could someone help me with

$$
\int_\gamma \frac{z}{(z-3)(z^n-1)}dz, 
\ n \in \mathbb{N}, 
\ \gamma(t)= 2 e^{2 \pi i t},
\ t \in [0,1]
$$

From the residue theorem we know the line integral of $f$ around $\gamma$ is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of residues of $f$.

For that matter I need to find the singularities for $f$.

I know that there is no need to find the singularity for $z-3$ because it is not included here $\gamma(t) = 2 e^{2 \pi i t}$.

However I am not sure how to find the singularity for $z^n-1$.
Is this true $z^n-1=0$ when $z=1$?

After I find the singularity how do I find the residue?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics in your question. As for the zeroes of $z^n - 1$ (and thus the singularities of $1/(z^n - 1)$: Any $n$-th root of unity will do, and there are exactly $n$ distinct such roots in the complex numbers: $e^{k 2 \pi i / n}$ for $0 \leqslant k < n$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $n$ singularities within the region bounded by the range of $\gamma$: $1$ $e^{2\pi i/n}$, $e^{4\pi i/n}$, …, and $e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n}$. And$$\operatorname{res}_{z=e^{2k\pi i/n}}\frac1{(z-3)(z^n-1)}=\frac1{(e^{2k\pi i/n}-3)ne^{2k(n-1)\pi i/n}}=\frac{e^{2k\pi i/n}}{n(e^{2k\pi i/n}-3)}.$$So, your integral is equal to$$2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{2k\pi i/n}}{n(e^{2k\pi i/n}-3)}.$$

Comment: Isn’t it easier to just consider residue at $z=3$ and $z=\infty$, since residues at all singularities and infinity sum up to zero? Imo it can be rather hard to deal with given sum of $n$ residues as $n$ gets larger.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei Yes, that's a fine approach.